# Find total number of intersections between a given set of ranges in python

Tags: python

What is the best way to count number of intersections of a given set of ranges.

For ex:
consider a list of range pairs[start,stop]

```
[[1,5], [3,7], [9,11], [6,8]]
```

Here there are total 2 intersections ,

[1,5] intersects with [3,7]

and [3,7] intersects with [6,8]

Comment: Define "best"...

Comment: can this really be said as intersections?

Comment: `[3:6]` which means 3, 4, 5 does not actually intersect with `[6:7]`, which is just 6. Is there anything common between them? or is my concept of intersection and ranges wrong?

Comment: @superbrain best as in quick or minimum steps

Comment: Depends on the data.

Comment: @CoolCloud yea youre right, increment the stop value by 1,i'll edit it in the question

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62995108/count-occurance-of-number-from-given-range/62995273#62995273

Comment: Maybe give us some code that you tried your self???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This problem can be done in nlogn time, of course you can do it in n^2 but it sounds like you want it time optimal.**

I'd call these interval overlaps, and it' a classic you'll find variants of it in many interview books. Here's how to do it:

1. Sort the items by the starts.
2. Now step through the items. Store a minheap for each item of where it ends, costs nlogn but doesn't matter, we already paid that. At each new start number you know how many of the previous intersections are overlapping. Remove the intervals that you've run past the end of.

Ends up being nlogn due to the search, doesn't matter that you're then stepping through in n time.

Example:

1. Sort to [1, 5], [3, 7], [6, 8], [9, 11]
2. Store a heap item that says it ends at 5.
3. Get to the second item. Heap is size 1, so add 1 to the overlap count. Add a 7 to the heap.
4. Get to the third item. Drop the 5 from the heap. Leave the 7, so add 1 again. Add the 8 to the heap.
5. Get to the 4th item, Drop the 7 and the 8, leaving an empty heap. Result is 2.

```py
import heapq
import operator

def mysol(v):

    overlaps = 0
    minheap = []

    vsorted = sorted(v, key=operator.itemgetter(0))

    for i in range(len(vsorted)):
        while len(minheap) > 0 and minheap[0] < vsorted[i][0]:
            heapq.heappop(minheap)

        overlaps += len(minheap)
        heapq.heappush(minheap, vsorted[i][1])

    return overlaps
```

Comment: there isn't any requirement in question for optimal time complexity, I don't see why "do not accept other answers" is necessary to include.

Comment: It's tagged algorithm, people are gonna flunk their interview quizzes if they think comparing all pairs is the solution. I'm not against solutions that are simple in a few lines, but the question smells like they want an optimal solution.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen The question does ask for "the best way" and in the comments the OP defined that as "best as in quick or minimum steps"...

Comment: the question was at no point tagged with the algorithm tag, just python, and minimum steps is still ambiguous for computer few steps or programmer few steps.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought it was tagged with algo since I monitor that

Comment: @carlos--updated your answer since we get the same results.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one-liner simple method which uses a list comprehension and `itertools.combinations` -

1. Iterate over combinations of lists
2. Turn them into ranges and then sets of those ranges
3. Take an intersection
4. Only return those with intersection = True

```
import itertools
r = [[1,5], [3,7], [9,11], [6,8]]

overlapping_ranges = [i for i in list(itertools.combinations(r, 2))\
                      if set(range(*i[0])).intersection(set(range(*i[1])))]

print('Count of overlapping ranges:',len(overlapping_ranges))
print(overlapping_ranges)
```

```
Count of overlapping ranges: 2
[([1, 5], [3, 7]), ([3, 7], [6, 8])]
```

Comment: this is returns count of overlaps, not count of overlapping ranges

Answer (score 2):

Modification of algorithm to find [Maximum Number of Overlaps](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-number-of-overlapping-intervals/) to compute number of overlaps instead.

**Approach**

- The idea is to store coordinates in a new vector of pair mapped with characters ‘x’ and ‘y’, to identify coordinates.
- Sort the vector.
- Traverse the vector, if an x coordinate is encountered it means a new range is added, so increment overlap count
- ```
   If count > 1, we have a new overlap
       so increment number of overlaps
  ```
- if y coordinate is encountered that means a range ends, so decrement overlap count
- The result is the number of overlaps

The algorithm complexity is O(n*log(n)) (from sort)

**Code**

```
def overlap(v): 
    # variable to store the maximum 
    # count 
    ans = 0
    count = 0
    data = [] 
  
    # storing the x and y 
    # coordinates in data vector 
    for i in range(len(v)): 
  
        # pushing the x coordinate 
        data.append([v[i][0], 'x']) 
  
        # pushing the y coordinate 
        data.append([v[i][1], 'y']) 
  
    # sorting of ranges 
    data = sorted(data) 
  
    # Traverse the data vector to 
    # count number of overlaps 
    for i in range(len(data)): 
  
        # if x occur it means a new range 
        # is added so we increase count 
        if (data[i][1] == 'x'): 
            count += 1
  
            if count > 1:
              ans += (count - 1) # new range intersets
                                 # count - 1 existing
                                 # ranges 


        # if y occur it means a range 
        # is ended so we decrease count 
        if (data[i][1] == 'y'): 
            count -= 1
  
  
    # Return number of overlaps 
    return ans
```

**Tests**

```
v = [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 3, 6 ] ] 
print(overlap(v)) # Output 2

v = [[1,5], [3,7], [9,11], [6,8]]
print(overlap(v)) # Output 2

v = [[1,5], [3,7], [9,11], [6,8], [1, 11]]
print(overlap(v))  # Output 6

v = [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 7 ], [3, 5], [4, 6] ] 
print(overlap(v))  # Output 5
```

Comment: I think it's right, or close. What should the answer be with v = [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 7 ], [3, 5], [4, 6] ] ? I get 3 from running it, but I think the 2nd element overlaps all three others, and the 1st and 3rd touch, and the 3rd and 4th touch too.

Comment: @Carlos--adjusted my answer.  When a new range starts, it overlaps the (count - 1) existing range which means we add (count-1) with the update rather than 1.  So now `v = [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 7 ], [3, 5], [4, 6] ]` produces an answer of 5.

Comment: Yes, I've got both our solutions side by side and they seem to give the same numbers. I'll upvote you.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [intspan](https://intspan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module, a solution could be:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> from intspan import intspan

>>> L = [[1,5], [3,7], [9,11], [6,8]]
>>> for s1, s2 in combinations(L, 2):
    if intspan.from_range(*s1) & intspan.from_range(*s2):
        print(s1, 'intersects', s2)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 5] intersects [3, 7]
[3, 7] intersects [6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

The lazy man's way would be to just generate ranges and check for set intersection, this is terrible for memory usage and not extendable to non integers, but it is short:

```
import itertools
def range_intersection(a,b):
    return len(set(range(*a)) & set(range(*b))) > 0

data = [[1,5], [3,7], [9,11], [6,8]]

for a,b in itertools.combinations(data, 2):
    if range_intersection(a,b):
        print(a,b)
```

Here `set(range(*a))` uses the start and end arguments to range then makes a set so it can be intersected with another range, then we just check if the length of intersection is greater than 0 (there are common elements).  `itertools.combinations` is to simplify checking all combinations of data together.

Comment: Your use of *range* doesn't include the 'stop' (right) number because in a range, the top most is not inclusive.

Comment: yes, as is consistent with all python slicing and range mechanics... When ever I see integer ranges in python I assume this is the desired behaviour unless explicitly mentioned otherwise and I think the [comments on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63319624/find-total-number-of-intersections-between-a-given-set-of-ranges-in-python/63319837?noredirect=1#comment111966896_63319624) did address this and the OP was modified so that the ranges did intersect when excluding the end point.

Comment: Ok, not meant as criticism. It seems in the comments by the original poster that he wanted it to be *inclusive* for the top number. (his reply to CoolCloud in the original post)

Answer (score 0):

The "portion" module might be helpful when you work with segments.

```
import portion as P
from itertools import combinations
li = [[1,5], [3,7], [9,11], [6,8]]

pairs=[el for el in combinations(li,2) if P.open(*el[0]) & P.open(*el[1]) != P.empty()]
```

print(pairs)

The output is a list of pairs that intersect:

```
[([1, 5], [3, 7]), ([3, 7], [6, 8])]
```